# Python List Comprehension of Dictionaries and OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, dictionary, list-comprehension

When I run this, Python sits and takes takes forever at `arr`. It just slowly consumes RAM and does nothing else:

```
import os
import glob
import cv2

root = r'path\to\img'

files = glob.iglob( os.path.join(root,'*.jpg') )

arr = [ { 'img_nm' : fl,
          'img' : cv2.imread( fl ) } for fl in files ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How many files in the directory?

Comment: I have 96,135 files

Comment: I'm trying to augment these images using parallel processing...iterator/generator approaches are also welcome

Comment: I would not use an iterator here.  It is unlikely that the overhead of a loop will be significant compared to the time to process the image.  Process the images one at  time all the way through.

Comment: For the sake of learning, is there a reason why my problem is occurring? Is it trying to read all images into memory at once?

Comment: Yes the list comprehension will be constructed in one go.  Instead write a standard `for` loop and process one image each loop and save the results, then loop again.

Comment: Excellent, that makes sense. That was it. I switched to reading one at a time and it works. I'll mark your response as the answer once StackOverflow allows me to in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

This [loop comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will construct the entire dataset in one go.

```
arr = [ { 'img_nm' : fl,
          'img' : cv2.imread( fl ) } for fl in files ]
```

Thus for lengthy processing, it will take a long time to run, and store the entire result in memory in the mean time.  Better would be to process each image one at a time with something like:

```
for fl in glob.iglob( os.path.join(root,'*.jpg') ):
    new_image_record = { 
        'img_nm' : fl,
        'img' : cv2.imread( fl )
    }
    # save new record
```